# I am trying to plot range of a target in a FMCW radar

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, continuous-signals, radar

I am working on the simulation of FMCW radar, and I am trying to figure out how to plot the target range using the impulse response of the beat signal. I have successfully generated the chirps and the beat signal applied Hanning window to the beat signal and then applied FFT and IFFT on the beat signal to get the range of the detected target. But there seems to be some problem in the plot the peak of the impulse response is stuck on a particular value and doesn't move even if I change the target range that I have set in the code while generating the chirps. I have checked all the formulas used by me in the code, but I still don't seem to get the right plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import pi  

# Parameters
chirp_duration = 10e-6
f0 = 1e6 
f1 = 10e6 
bandwidth = f1 - f0
no_samp = 1000
c = 3e8  # Speed of light
f_step = (f1 - f0) / no_samp
slope = (f1 - f0) / chirp_duration


# Define target parameters
target_range = 600  # Distance to the target  in meters can go up to 
target_velocity = 50  # Velocity of the target in m/s


#create axis for transmitted chirp
time_delay = 2 * target_range / c
change_in_frequency = f_step * time_delay
frequency_at_time = f0 + change_in_frequency
tt_axis = np.linspace(0, chirp_duration, no_samp)
tf_axis = np.arange(frequency_at_time, f1, f_step)
changedt_axis = tt_axis + time_delay

# Generate the transmitted chirp signal

tchirp = np.cos(2 * pi * tf_axis * tt_axis)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(changedt_axis, tchirp )
plt.xlabel('Range (meters)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude (dB)')
plt.title('transchirp')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()  

# Frequency and time axes
rf_axis = np.arange(f0, f1, f_step)
rt_axis = np.linspace(0, chirp_duration, len(rf_axis))

# # Calculate the phase shift for the target
phase_shift = -2 * np.pi * (f1 - f0) * 2 * target_velocity / c

# Apply the phase shift to the received chirp signal for the target
rchirp = np.cos((2 * np.pi * rf_axis * rt_axis) + phase_shift)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(rt_axis, rchirp )
plt.xlabel('Range (meters)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude (dB)')
plt.title('rec chirp')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()  

# Generate the beat signal by mixing the transmitted and received signals
beat_signal = tchirp * rchirp

# Apply Hanning window to the beat signal
hanning_window = np.hanning(len(beat_signal))
beat_signal_hanning = beat_signal * hanning_window

# Compute the FFT of the beat signal to obtain the impulse response, Perform FFT shift to 
center the frequency components
impulse_response = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(beat_signal_hanning, 2048))

#Normalize the impulse response
impulse_response /= np.max(impulse_response)

# # Apply IFFT to obtain the range profile
range_profile = np.fft.ifft(impulse_response)

# Generate a range axis (assuming a sample rate of fs)
max_range = c * chirp_duration / 2  # Calculate the maximum range based on the speed of light 
and the chirp duration
ranges = np.linspace(0, max_range, len(range_profile))  # Create a range axis that spans from 
0 to max_range
print(max_range)

# Plot the range profile
plt.figure()
plt.plot(ranges, np.abs(range_profile))
plt.xlabel('Range (meters)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.title('Range Profile with Hanning Window')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The output that I am getting is as follows. The peak in the below image remains constant even if the range in the code is changed.
[image]

The plot changes if I plot the FFT. But in this plot too the point where the plot occurs is the same even if I change the target range in the code.
[image]